# "URL-safe CSRF tokens are now the default" warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

I have recently upgraded from Rails 6 to 7 and even though I have `urlsafe_csrf_tokens` set to true:

`config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_1.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.action_controller.urlsafe_csrf_tokens = true
```

when I start the application I keep getting the following warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: URL-safe CSRF tokens are now the default. Use 6.1 defaults or above.
```

I would like to understand why?

Comment: What is the version number specified in `config.load_defaults`, probably the warning could be because of that?

Comment: @Deepesh, I have `config.load_defaults 5.2` in the application.rb. So, I have to just load 6.1 defaults in order to fix this? This seems a bit of an overkill.

Comment: @spacemonkey same here, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 16):

In `application.rb` update your `config.load_defaults` with the current rails version as follows:

```
config.load_defaults 7.0
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

Yes, you have to increment your `config.load_defaults` at least for `6.1` (but preferably `7.0` since you are on Rails 7 already).

**Long answer:**

As far as I can tell from reading Rails repo, you are getting this message because starting with Rails 7.0 developers are not supposed to set `urlsafe_csrf_tokens`  config option at all. It is [supposed to be enabled by default by Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L99). This is basically a preparation for Rails 7.1 in which this option [will be removed](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb).

The only solution is to upgrade your `config.load_defaults` from 5.2 to 6.1 at least (although I'd recommend 7.0 since you are on Rails 7 already). Actually I think I can even add that until you have `config.load_defaults 7.0` in your app you can't say you have fully upgraded to Rails 7 since removing all `new_framework_defaults_X_Y.rb` files and incrementing `config.load_defaults` is a part of the upgrade flow as [described here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#configure-framework-defaults):

> To allow you to upgrade to new defaults one by one, the update task has created a file config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_X.Y.rb (with the desired Rails version in the filename). You should enable the new configuration defaults by uncommenting them in the file; this can be done gradually over several deployments. Once your application is ready to run with new defaults, you can remove this file and flip the config.load_defaults value.