# 'URL-safe CSRF tokens are now the default. Use 6.1 defaults or above' warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I recently upgraded my application from rails 6.1 to 7.0 but I am seeing the below error while running the tests.

```
URL-safe CSRF tokens are now the default. Use 6.1 defaults or above.
```

I have already updated the `load_defaults` in the `config/application.rb` file but I'm still seeing this error.

```
config.load_defaults 7.0
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["URL-safe CSRF tokens are now the default" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72110385/url-safe-csrf-tokens-are-now-the-default-warning)

Comment: @markets I have already implemented the change advised in that question but that did not solve the issue.